# Improve programs performance by splitting long running task into separate processes

Tags: c#, multithreading, performance, process, parallel-processing

I've read that when you run a long running operation in separate threads (in parallel) there will be noticeable improvement in performance when your PC has multiple processor cores. In C# there is a function `Parallel.ForEach` which, how I understand, splits the long running operation in separate threads which are ran on each processor core. Although, if there is only one core, this function will run as a simple `Foreach` loop (synchronous). Also, if you are creating more threads than there is processor cores, it may even have a negative impact.

I was thinking of creating a separate console application, pass `args` to it and run it's .exe on multiple processes like `start -WindowStyle Hidden SeparateProcess.exe`.

**Edit:** 
I already created a console app like this

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(200);
            Console.WriteLine("" + i);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine(Guid.NewGuid() + ": Process finalized.");
    }
}
```

Then, using powershell executed it many times:

```
For ($i=0; $i -lt 10; $i++){
start -WindowStyle Normal SeparateProcess.exe 
}
```

Will this improve program performance when ran on single core?

Note: The long running task is Emgu CV image computing algorithm.

Comment: Multithreading isn't for only taking advantage of multiple cores.  Depending on what the application and its threads do, a multithreaded application running on a single core machine may still be more performant than a single threaded application running on a single core. 

One big downside to to multiple processes is that they cannot share memory or resources, while a single process with multiple threads can.

Comment: Your process isn't CPU-bound -- it just sleeps most of the time. What would improving performance look like?  It will still sleep 200 milliseconds 100 times and take about the same time. The writes will all take the same time.

Comment: @RavB There *are* plenty of reasons to use multiple threads on machines that only have a single core (after all, threading has been commonly used for many decades, while multi-core computers have only been common for just over a single decade) but those reasons aren't performance.  On a single core machine multithreaded code will always be *less* performant (as you get the same work done but have the threading overhead) but can be useful despite the threading overhead.

Answer (score 1):

You should check yourself by trying it, but ...

> Is there a way to improve long running task performance even when there is only one core?

Yes, but obviously not by running it in parallel.  You would use a performance analyzer on the code to find out which parts were taking the most time and try to rewrite it in a more optimized way.

EDIT based on comments:

If you are trying to do image-processing with CV and the thing you are doing is CPU-bound (maxes out the processor while running), then parallelizing it isn't going to help on a single core (they will compete with each other for CPU).

If the thing you are doing has to wait for I/O to complete, then parallelizing it will allow some of the work to go forward while other processes wait on the I/O.

It depends on what you are doing -- you should probably close this question and ask a much more specific one with details on exactly what you are trying to do and how CPU-intensive that task is.

(BTW, if you can, one way to make image processing go faster is to resize the image beforehand -- many things you might try to do with an image work fine on a smaller version -- for example: face detection).

Comment: The problem is that it is not my written code which takes long time to complete, it is- EmguCV image computing algorithm.

Comment: It takes the time it takes (also, it's pretty likely to be doing that as fast as it can -- CV is pretty well written).